# Postfix / Dovecot Mail appears in logs, but not in its respective folder

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, imap, dovecot

I'm currently trying to set up Postfix with Dovecot, but something does not seem to work the way it should be.

For some reason, mails I sent to my mail account appear in the logs, but do not become relocated into the respective mailbox. The logs are not displaying any error, so I am pretty much left without a clue where the problem might be. Additionally, I have not set up any of the servers at any point, so I can't really tell what I might be missing here.

Hope you guys can give me a hint.

Edit: I'm also using a [frontend webinterface](http://www.afterlogic.org/webmail-lite) which lets me log in, but no mails can be displayed in its interface either.

**tree -aps**

```
root /var/customers/mail/webmail/mail.domain.net/server/Maildir # tree -aps
.
|-- [drwx------        4096]  .Drafts
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  cur
|   |-- [-rw-------          51]  dovecot-uidlist
|   |-- [-rw-------         248]  dovecot.index.log
|   |-- [-rw-------           0]  maildirfolder
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  new
|   `-- [drwx------        4096]  tmp
|-- [drwx------        4096]  .Sent
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  cur
|   |-- [-rw-------          51]  dovecot-uidlist
|   |-- [-rw-------         248]  dovecot.index.log
|   |-- [-rw-------           0]  maildirfolder
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  new
|   `-- [drwx------        4096]  tmp
|-- [drwx------        4096]  .Spam
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  cur
|   |-- [-rw-------          51]  dovecot-uidlist
|   |-- [-rw-------         248]  dovecot.index.log
|   |-- [-rw-------           0]  maildirfolder
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  new
|   `-- [drwx------        4096]  tmp
|-- [drwx------        4096]  .Trash
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  cur
|   |-- [-rw-------          51]  dovecot-uidlist
|   |-- [-rw-------         156]  dovecot.index.log
|   |-- [-rw-------           0]  maildirfolder
|   |-- [drwx------        4096]  new
|   `-- [drwx------        4096]  tmp
|-- [drwx------        4096]  cur
|-- [-rw-------          51]  dovecot-uidlist
|-- [-rw-------           8]  dovecot-uidvalidity
|-- [-r--r--r--           0]  dovecot-uidvalidity.55020f8f
|-- [-rw-------         432]  dovecot.index.log
|-- [-rw-------          96]  dovecot.mailbox.log
|-- [drwx------        4096]  new
|-- [-rw-------          23]  subscriptions
`-- [drwx------        4096]  tmp

19 directories, 18 files
```

**mail.log**

```
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/pickup[12736]: 06AE0736F6C5: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/cleanup[15499]: 06AE0736F6C5: message-id=<20150312235341.06AE0736F6C5@mail.domain.net>
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/qmgr[12737]: 06AE0736F6C5: from=<root@mail.domain.net>, size=443, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/trivial-rewrite[15500]: warning: do not list domain mail.domain.net in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/local[15503]: warning: database /etc/aliases.db is older than source file /etc/aliases
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/local[15503]: 06AE0736F6C5: to=<server@mail.domain.net>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 13 00:53:41 v220110897556081 postfix/qmgr[12737]: 06AE0736F6C5: removed
```

**postconf -Mf**

```
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup     fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail
    ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender
    $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe
    flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
    ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
    ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

Comment: Show your `main.cf` file, it should have `local_transport = virtual` and `virtual_transport = dovecot`. It's now delivering to the standard mailbox, which is probably `/var/mail/username`.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the default `local_transport = local` as the log says *delivered to mailbox*.

You need to tell `postfix` to use `dovecot` as the transport for local deliveries. you can do this as follows:

Edit your `main.cf` file and modify it to have the following lines:

```
local_transport = virtual
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Don't forget to reload `postfix` to activate the new config.